# How to take instance name which numbering by array and the number can be operated?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, button, instance

The intention of the following ActionScript script is to allow a player to move by clicking a button, wherein `myarray` represents places they are allowed to move to.

I'm having trouble making my click event handler work properly. For example, how can I extract the `(x, y)` coordinates of the click from the `MouseEvent` event in order to perform further processing?

```
a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bergerak);
b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bergerak);
c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bergerak);
d.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bergerak);

function bergerak (Event:MouseEvent) {
    var namatombol:String = Event.currentTarget.name;
    var myarray:Array = [];
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        myarray[i] = this["kotak" + i];
        if (namatombol == "a") {
            MovieClip(root).pemain.x = MovieClip(root).myarray[i].x;
            MovieClip(root).pemain.y = MovieClip(root).myarray[i].y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand... What's the problem?

Comment: Please variable Event starts not with capitalized letter but event

Comment: My problem is how to take the instace name in x = MovieClip(root).myarray[i].x;
            MovieClip(root).pemain.y = MovieClip(root).myarray[i].y; ...........myarray[i] is the instace name of movieclips i is the number of the instace like shape1,shape2,shape 3

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you're willing to move a player display object (like a MovieClip) to the clicked button position on stage. In this case, your function will be as follows:

```
function bergerak(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(root).pemain.x = event.target.x;
    MovieClip(root).pemain.y = event.target.y;
}
```

Comment: are target .x and target .y equal to pemain1.x and pemain1.y and it'll continue to pemain100.x and pemain100.x?

Comment: Continue the same way:
`for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        myarray[i] = this["kotak" + i];
        if (namatombol == "a") {
            MovieClip(root).pemain.x = event.target.x;
            MovieClip(root).pemain.y = event.target.y;
        }
    }`